# Always get a System.OutOfMemoryException from SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, out-of-memory

I am using `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

However, it behaving strangely since this morning, that it keeps giving me 'System.OutOfMemoryException' errors, even I am simply running a `SELECT 1` command.

I am wondering what could cause such problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: Where do you get the exception, in SSMS? Do you have free memory at all?

Comment: Back to basics, but: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I still haven't figure out what is wrong with my environment. However, I dealt with it with a simple reboot.

Hope this is helpful.